# Android - All users have to install Google Play Services?

Tags: react-native-maps

For devleopment I have to do this:

If not installed yet, you have to install the following packages :

```
Extras / Google Play services
Extras / Google Repository
Android 6.0 (API 23) / Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image Rev. 19
Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.3
```

Is this for development only? Or do all my users of the app have to also download Google Play Services etc?

Yes I know this isn't really a question for stackoverflow, but where else can I ask this question? They are not letting me ask this in the github issues either.

I also can't test this, because react-native-maps isn't working for me, it keeps crashing. I wash hoping to learn if its worth the effort to fix the crash. If users have to install a bunch of stuff to use this, then its not worth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using services provided by Google Play Services like Maps, or push messages, location services or in-app payments then yes, your users must have it installed too. If you are not using Google Play Services, then it's not required.

But if required, they have to install Google Play Services app from Play Store, not development stuff like you listed:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

**EDIT**

> How come Google doesnt defalt install this?

Google Play Services or apps like Calendar, GMail etc are NOT part of Android. These are Google applications and may or may not come preinstalled, depending on licenses phone/tablet manufacturer purchased from Google. As Android can perfectly live w/o these apps, some devices does not include it or come with alternatives (i.e. using other providers than Google).

> I don't know even know where the proper place to tell them would be

Your app should check if Google Play Services exists usually on start before it start using it. See [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#ensure_devices_have_the_google_play_services_apk) which discuss this.

Comment: Darn, thanks Marcin. That seems like a headache, to tell them to go install other stuff just to use my thing. How come Google doesnt defalt install this? I don't know even know where the proper place to tell them would be. I just want my app to work. :( I tried to accept answer but they are saying i have to wait 9 minutes.

Comment: Thanks very much sir for your in depth answer.

Answer (score 1):

Weird, I just clicked on "Google Maps" on my Android Simulator and it made my `react-native-maps` start working.

There was a licence agreement when I clicked Google Maps on the phone, so as soon as I accepted it, react-native-maps started working.

Comment: I also had another problem later where the map loaded blank but appeared when I rotated the device simulator screen. The problem ending up being that I was using a `x86_64` virtual device image, but I needed to use a `x86` one. I started using that in the simulator and the map loaded properly by default. Woot.

Comment: These images I refer to are in your Android Studio > Virtual Devices area. Build a new virtual device using `Nougat x86`, and your map should work if you have all the other Android stuff installed especially including Play Services.